Types for iterating over map of functions and props
I have a map of functions (React components) (the component field) and their props (the props field) that I would like to iterate over and call component(props). The problem is that in the loop, TypeScript complains because the types are too broad. Here's an example (Playground link):
const c1 = ({ }: { c1p1: number, c1p2: number }) => { }
const c2 = ({ }: { c2p1: number }) => { }
const c3 = ({ }: { c3p1: number }) => { }

const components = {
    c1: {
        component: c1,
        props: { c1p1: 11, c1p2: 12 }
    },
    c2: {
        component: c2,
        props: { c2p1: 21 }
    },
    c3: {
        component: c3,
        props: { c3p1: 31 }
    }
}

const selectedComponentNames: Array<keyof typeof components> = ["c1", "c2"]
selectedComponentNames.map(o => {
    const { component, props } = components[o]
    component(props)
})

The error I get:

Argument of type '{ c1p1: number; c1p2: number; } | { c2p1: number; } | { c3p1: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ c1p1: number; c1p2: number; } & { c2p1: number; } & { c3p1: number; }'.
Type '{ c1p1: number; c1p2: number; }' is not assignable to type '{ c1p1: number; c1p2: number; } & { c2p1: number; } & { c3p1: number; }'.
Property 'c2p1' is missing in type '{ c1p1: number; c1p2: number; }' but required in type '{ c2p1: number; }'.(2345)

Is there a way to make TypeScript understand it's using the props field with the component field of the same object?

You need the map callback to be generic and you need to give components a mapped type that explicitly describes the relationship, see this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what's missing?

Thank you very much! That does indeed answer the question I posted. I tried to apply it to the real problem, but I guess I'm missing something there. Will have to take a deeper look tomorrow.

Depending on the complexity of this task, is there a reason you don't just have one functioning defining a potential array of numbers here? IE:
const c = (cs: number[]) => { }
const components = {
    c1: {
        component: c,
        props: [11, 12]
    },
    c2: {
        component: c,
        props: [21]
    },
    c3: {
        component: c,
        props: [31]
    }
}

const selectedComponentNames: Array<keyof typeof components> = ["c1", "c2"]
selectedComponentNames.map(o => {
    const { component, props } = components[o]
    component(props)
})


@jcalz I was missing the map annotation before, I could apply this to my problem now successfully.

@MasonA the types are actually more complex than I posted here.

You're essentially running into TypeScript's lack of direct support for correlated union types as described in microsoft/TypeScript#30581.  Inside your map callback, the type of component is a union of functions ((x:{c1p1:number,c1p2:number})=>void)|((x:{c2p1:number})=>void)|((x:{c3p1:number})=>void) and the type of props is a union of argument types {c1p1:number,c1p2:number}|{c2p1:number}|{c3p1:number}. And that's all TypeScript knows about these variables. For all TypeScript understands, component could be the first member of the union while props is the third member of the union. And then you'd be passing in the wrong argument to the function. That's not safe, so TypeScript complains.  Of course we know that the operation is safe, because the type of component is correlated with the type of props. But TypeScript has no way to represent correlated union types directly.
The recommended approach in cases like this is to refactor to use generics instead of unions, as described in microsoft/TypeScript#47109. The goal is for the type of props to be some single generic type, and for component to be a single function type whose parameter is the same single generic type as props.  In order for this to happen, you need to express the components object as a type that explicitly describes this sort of generic relationship between the key and the value.  First we need a "base" interface that maps between keys of components and a relevant props type:
interface PropsMap {
    c1: { c1p1: number, c1p2: number },
    c2: { c2p1: number },
    c3: { c3p1: number }
}

Then the type of components can be given a mapped type that makes the relationship between component and props explicitly depend on the generic type parameter K:
type ComponentAndPropsMap = { [K in keyof PropsMap]: {
    component: (props: PropsMap[K]) => void,
    props: PropsMap[K]
} }

const components: ComponentAndPropsMap = {
    c1: {
        component: (({ }) => { }),
        props: { c1p1: 11, c1p2: 12 }
    },
    c2: {
        component: (({ }) => { }),
        props: { c2p1: 21 }
    },
    c3: {
        component: (({ }) => { }),
        props: { c3p1: 31 }
    }
}

Finally, you can make the map() callback generic in a key K of the components object, and it works:
selectedComponentNames.map(<K extends keyof PropsMap>(o: K) => {
    const { component, props } = components[o]
    component(props)
})

If you inspect the types, props is of type PropsMap[K], while component is of type (props: PropsMap[K]) => void. The call component(props) therefore succeeds, because TypeScript sees that the argument type is identical to the required parameter type.
Note that if you just make map()'s callback generic without annotating the components variable as ComponentAndPropsMap, you'll get the same error you originally had. That's because while the generic callback is an important component, it's not sufficient. If the type of components is just an object type, TypeScript won't see that there is a generic relationship in its properties. It will therefore revert back to the union types inside the callback, and you're stuck. Even though the annotated and unannotated type of components are equivalent structurally, their differing representations causes TypeScript to treat them differently. This is all spelled out inside microsoft/TypeScript#47109 linked above, but I'm pointing it out here because it is often surprising to people that two types which look the same will behave differently.
Playground link to code
